# ECS + EC2 using CloudFormation stuck in CREATE_IN_PRO

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

Stack creation would get stuck in CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. The resource Service specifically. The stack creation would complete without it. This is what the cloudformation looks like. I have checked CloudTrail but can't find anything out of the ordinary.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Amazon ECS Preview Quickstart Template
Parameters:
  SubnetID:
    Type: String
  SubnetID2:
    Type: String
  ClusterName:
    Description: Name of your Amazon ECS Cluster
    Type: String
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid Amazon ECS Cluster.
    Default: TestCluster
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    ConstraintDescription: must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair.
  InstanceType:
    Description: Container Instance type
    Type: String
    Default: t2.micro
    AllowedValues:
    - t2.micro
    - t2.small
    - t2.medium
    - m3.medium
    - m3.large
    - m3.xlarge
    - m3.2xlarge
    - c3.large
    - c3.xlarge
    - c3.2xlarge
    - c3.4xlarge
    - c3.8xlarge
    - r3.large
    - r3.xlarge
    - r3.2xlarge
    - r3.4xlarge
    - r3.8xlarge
    - i2.xlarge
    - i2.2xlarge
    - i2.4xlarge
    - i2.8xlarge
    - hi1.4xlarge
    - hs1.8xlarge
    - cr1.8xlarge
    - cc2.8xlarge
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid EC2 instance type.
  SSHLocation:
    Description: " The IP address range that can be used to SSH to the EC2 instances"
    Type: String
    MinLength: '9'
    MaxLength: '18'
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
    AllowedPattern: "(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})/(\\d{1,2})"
    ConstraintDescription: must be a valid IP CIDR range of the form x.x.x.x/x.
Mappings:
  AWSInstanceType2Arch:
    t2.micro:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.small:
      Arch: HVM64
    t2.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.medium:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    m3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    c3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.large:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    r3.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.2xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    i2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hi1.4xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    hs1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cr1.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
    cc2.8xlarge:
      Arch: HVM64
  AWSRegionArch2AMI:
    us-east-1:
      HVM64: ami-34ddbe5c
Resources:
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: ClusterName
  LogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: deployment-example-log-group
  ContainerInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      IamInstanceProfile:
        Ref: ECSIamInstanceProfile
      ImageId:
        Fn::FindInMap:
        - AWSRegionArch2AMI
        - Ref: AWS::Region
        - Fn::FindInMap:
          - AWSInstanceType2Arch
          - Ref: InstanceType
          - Arch
      InstanceType:
        Ref: InstanceType
      SecurityGroups:
      - Ref: ECSQuickstartSecurityGroup
      KeyName:
        Ref: KeyName
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Join:
          - ''
          - - "#!/bin/bash -xe\n"
            - echo ECS_CLUSTER=
            - Ref: ClusterName
            - " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n"
  ECSQuickstartSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enable HTTP access via SSH
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: '22'
        ToPort: '22'
        CidrIp:
          Ref: SSHLocation
  ECSIamInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
      - Ref: ECSQuickstartRole
  ECSQuickstartRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: ECSQuickstart
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: ecs:*
            Resource: "*"

  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: deployment-example-task
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512
      # NetworkMode: awsvpc
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref ECSQuickstartRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - 
          Name: engine
          Image:  gcr.io/xxxxx
          Environment: 
            - Name: db_instance
              Value: "clouform2"
            - Name: LOG_LEVEL
              Value: 1
            - Name: HOST 
              Value: 0.0.0.0
            - Name: HTTP_PORT
              Value: 8181
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 8181
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
        - 
          Name: encyou
          Image:   gcr.io/xxxx3
          DependsOn:
            - Condition: START
              ContainerName: engine
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
        - 
          Name: packager
          Image:   gcr.io/xxxxx
          DependsOn:
            - Condition: START
              ContainerName: engine
          LogConfiguration:
            LogDriver: awslogs
            Options:
              awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
              awslogs-group: !Ref LogGroup
              awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - EC2

  Service:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    DependsOn: ContainerInstance
    Properties:
      ServiceName: ServiceName
      Cluster: !Ref Cluster
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 75
      DesiredCount: 2
      TaskDefinition: !Ref 'TaskDefinition'
      LaunchType: EC2
```

I would see that the Service, although it is the resource that get's stuck, would successfully be registered in the cluster but tasks would not.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using **wrong cluster names**. Your cluster will be just called `ClusterName`, not `TestCluster`. Subsequently, your instance will be trying to register with non-existing cluster.

This is because instead of:

```
ClusterName: ClusterName
```

there should be:

```
ClusterName: !Ref ClusterName
```

Please note that there could be other issues, not yet apparent though. What's more, you are using custom images `gcr.io/xxxxx` witch does not allow to re-produce the possible issues.

Comment: I made the changes and the EC2 instance now appears on the cluster. Sadly, the tasks still absent from the cluster and "create service'. I have also made updates to how I distributed CPU and storage among containers.

Comment: You can try run with the nginx image to replicate the problem.

Comment: @Paschal There could be many causes. Your question does not provide much info. For example, are you using default VPC or custom vpc? If custom, is it correctly setup to allow internet access. What instance are you using in your tests? If its too small, not tasks will fit on it.